# I am trying to build an app, that creates a notification when wifi state is changed

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am building an app that sends a notification when wifi connection is established. Since I am using android 9 setting intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml doesn't work.

I created a custom BroadcastReceiver, that creates a notification, and it works if I register receiver in onCreate.

Here is the registerReceiver part of the code in onCreate (it works when app is opened)

```
receiver = new WifiStateReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class WifiStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TEST", "IT WORKS!");
    }
}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
.
.
.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
.
.
.
        <receiver
            android:name=".WifiStateReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

.
.
.
```

After I close my app this doesn't work anymore. So I need some kind of service that never closes, but I'm not sure how battery inefficient this method is. Is there a way to run a service when wifi connection/state changes? And as I already said, putting intent-filter in AndroidManifest doesn't seem to work as I am using android 9.

Comment: You need to create a background process and then check for wifi status in it

Comment: @jpsingh how much does this drain battery if I make it always running?

Comment: you don't need to run it always. You can add a job schedular, and start the process at required time intervals to check wifi state. It will increase you performance as well as would drain less amount of battery